# Swift pass an array as argument error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just starting Swift. Can someone please explain to me why I can pass array as an argument (byRoundingCorners:)

```
UIBezierPath(
        roundedRect: self.bounds,
        byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft],
        cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
```

But passing it in variable, produces error

```
var corners = [UIRectCorner.topLeft, UIRectCorner.bottomLeft]
let path = UIBezierPath(
        roundedRect: self.bounds,
        byRoundingCorners: corners,
        cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
```

**"Cannot convert value of type '[UIRectCorner]' to expected argument type 'UIRectCorner'"**

Comment: Enough answers already, but someone might add that OptionSet (indirectly) inherits from ExpressibleByArrayLiteral, and that is what allows to pass a literal array in the initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an array. It's an `OptionSet`. The `byRoundingCorners` parameter expects a type of `UIRectCorner` which extends `OptionSet`.

If you update your declaration of `corners` to:

```
var corners: UIRectCorner = [.topLeft, .bottomLeft]
```

then your code will work as expected.

The `[ ]` syntax is not really an array here, it's a list of options for the set.

Your first attempt works because the compiler can infer the data type (`UIRectCorner`) from the parameter.

But when you did:

```
var corners = [UIRectCorner.topLeft, UIRectCorner.bottomLeft]
```

the inferred type is an array of `UIRectCorner`, not `UIRectCorner`. By adding the `: UIRectCorner` to the line, you make it clear what the type is and the syntax using `[ ]` is properly interpreted as a list of options instead of as an array.

As mentioned by Martin R (thanks), `OptionSet` extends `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` which is what allows the array-like literal syntax to be used to assign a value to `UIRectCorner`.

Answer (score 3):

[`UIRectCorner`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirectcorner) in an [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset), so when you write `[.topLeft, .bottomLeft]` in your function call, Swift automatically creates an instance of `UIRectCorner` from that array literal.

However, when you write

```
var corners = [UIRectCorner.topLeft, UIRectCorner.bottomLeft]
```

you create an array of `UIRectCorner` option sets, instead of a single option set containing all the different cases.

You can get around this by specifying the type of `corners` as `UIRectCorner`. This will also allow you to infer the type in the array literal:

```
var corners: UIRectCorner = [.topLeft, .topRight]
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 example for the ones who had problem tried append and finally found insert is the way to go for a variable situation.

```
    var cornersToRound: UIRectCorner = []
    if topLeftRounded { cornersToRound.insert(.topLeft) }
    if topRightRounded { cornersToRound.insert(.topRight) }
    if bottomRightRounded { cornersToRound.insert(.bottomRight) }
    if bottomLeftRounded { cornersToRound.insert(.bottomLeft) }
```