# Why is the type of view.layer.maskedCorners CACornerMask and not [CACornerMask]?

Tags: swift

I am trying to mask certain corners of a view layer depending on @IBInspectable parameters. to mask the top left and top right corners, for example, the following code is used:

```swift
view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
```

I tried to define a new array of CACornerMask objects and then append the appropriate corners based on the @IBInspectable parameters

```swift
var cornersToMask = [CACornerMask]()
cornersToMask.append(.layerMinXMinYCorner)
```

however, when I try to assign this array to view.layer.maskedCorners, I get the following error:

`view.layer.maskedCorners = cornersToMask`

***Cannot assign value of type '[CACornerMask]' to type 'CACornerMask'***

why can the array from the first code snippet be assigned to view.layer.maskedCorners but mine can not? is this actually an array or does [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner] mean something else here?

Comment: `CACornerMask` extends `OptionSet`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift pass an array as argument error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195165/swift-pass-an-array-as-argument-error)

Comment: ah ok, thank you. is there a way to append to an OptionSet?

Comment: Sure. Look at the OptionSet (then SetAlgebra) documentation.